# Using values selected from a javascript based select menu in shiny

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I am using the jQuery plugin [ComboTree](https://github.com/kirlisakal/combo-tree) to display a tree-like select menu in my shiny app.[image]

I am having trouble retrieving those values (e.g. `c("Item 2", "Item 2-1")`) to use in some output. So the issue here is to retrieve whatever values are selected from the select menu (`$("example").val();`).

`ui.r`:

```
ui <- function(){
  fluidPage(
    tags$head(
      tags$script(src = "comboTreePlugin.js"), 
      tags$script(src = "icontains.js"), 
      tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "comboTreeStyle.css")
    ),
    includeScript("myData.json"),
    # layouy content ----
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(width = 3,
                   tags$input(type = "text", id = "example", placeholder = "Select"), 
                   uiOutput("comboTreeMenu")
      ), 
      mainPanel(width = 9)
    )
  ) 
}
```

`server.r`:

```
server <- function(input, output, session){
  output$comboTreeMenu <- renderUI({
    includeScript("www/example.js")
    })

  # want to do some manipulation with the resulting selections from the 
  # combo tree. Something along the lines of:

  # selections <- eventReactive(input$click, {
  #   return(input$comboTreeSelections)
  # })
}
```

`example.js`:

```
comboTree1 = $('#example').comboTree({
  source: myData,
  isMultiple: true
});
```

`myData.json`:

```
var myData = [
  {
    id: 0,
    title: 'Item 1 '
  }, {
    id: 1,
    title: 'Item 2',
    subs: [
      {
        id: 10,
        title: 'Item 2-1'
      }, {
        id: 11,
        title: 'Item 2-2'
      }, {
        id: 12,
        title: 'Item 2-3'
      }
      ]
  }, {
    id: 2,
    title: 'Item 3'
  }
  ];
```

I've tried to add an extra piece of js script like so:

```
selectedValues = $("#example").val();

Shiny.onInputChange("comboTreeSelections", selectedValues);
```

Thank you!

Comment: Did you check out this package [shinyTree](https://github.com/shinyTree/shinyTree)?

Comment: Thanks @SeGa. Definitely checking `shinyTree`. I will leave this question opened though in case someone has a different suggestion or solution. Cheers

Comment: Your js-file might have a wrong name too (combroTreePlugin). Shouldnt it be comboTreePlugin without "r"?

Comment: Ooops, I mistakenly added an 'r' to my `.js` source plugin file. The app works though (as evidenced by screenshot). I will correct it in the question anyway. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a quick fix, as I don't really recommend using a pure jQuery plugin, since you will have to write all the interaction between combotree and Shiny yourself. But when you're only interested in the actual selected items, you could do this:

In `comboTreePlugin.js` change the function at line 129 to:

```
this._elemItemsTitle.on('click', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    if (_this.options.isMultiple)
        _this.multiItemClick(this);
    else
        _this.singleItemClick(this);

    var selItem = comboTree1.getSelectedItemsTitle();
    Shiny.onInputChange('selTitle', selItem);
});
```

This example will only work, when you really click on an item, it wont fire when you select an item by hitting Enter. You would have to copy/paste the last 2 lines above in the `keydown`-event handler (code 13).

Then you can access the variable `selTitle` with `input$selTitle` in Shiny.

---

Here's a small ShinyApp which prints out the selected titles:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- {fluidPage(
    tags$head(
      tags$script(src = "comboTreePlugin.js"), 
      tags$script(src = "icontains.js"), 
      tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "comboTreeStyle.css")
    ),
    includeScript("www/myData.json"),
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(width = 3,
                   tags$input(type = "text", id = "example", placeholder = "Select"), 
                   uiOutput("comboTreeMenu"),
                   verbatimTextOutput("selected")
      ), 
      mainPanel(width = 9)
    )
)}

server <- function(input, output, session){
  output$comboTreeMenu <- renderUI({
    includeScript("www/example.js")
  })

  output$selected <- renderPrint({
    req(input$selTitle)
    print(input$selTitle)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks for this @SeGa. I still wonder if there is a simpler solution by injecting some `js`  code on `ui.r`. Something along the lines of `tags$script('$(document).on("shiny:sessioninitialized", function() {$("#example").on("change", function() {var = $("#example").val(); Shiny.onInputChange("selTitle", var);});})`. Thanks again!

Comment: I think thats the easiest way. Since `#example` is just a select input with a click event, it wont trigger everytime the selection change just when you click inside the select input. You may have to add some event delegation on that comboTree list. That might work. I tried to add some click events on .ComboTreeItemParent/.ComboTreeItemChlid/.comboTreeDropDownContainer without success.

Answer (score 1):

I found another method, where you dont have to mess with the source code and just inject some javascript.
This will trigger a `setInterval` function, when the dropdown is visible/openend and will re-run every 500ms.

```
library(shiny)

js <- HTML("
$(function() {
  var selection = setInterval(function() {
    if($('.comboTreeDropDownContainer').is(':visible')) {
      var selItem = comboTree1.getSelectedItemsTitle();
      Shiny.onInputChange('selTitle', selItem)
    }
  }, 500);
});
")

ui <- {fluidPage(
    tags$head(
      tags$script(src = "comboTreePlugin.js"), 
      tags$script(src = "icontains.js"), 
      tags$script(js),
      tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "comboTreeStyle.css")
    ),
    includeScript("www/myData.json"),
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(width = 3,
                   tags$input(type = "text", id = "example", placeholder = "Select"), 
                   uiOutput("comboTreeMenu"),
                   verbatimTextOutput("selected")
      ), 
      mainPanel(width = 9)
    )
)}

server <- function(input, output, session){
  output$comboTreeMenu <- renderUI({
    includeScript("www/example.js")
  })

  output$selected <- renderPrint({
    req(input$selTitle)
    print(input$selTitle)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you. So `setInterval()` runs "indefinitely" every .5s whenever the combo tree menu is visible. Brilliant

Comment: Hi.. I tried to run the code and it is not working, is it possible to create zip folder with r code and json , js files. Thanks

Comment: Did you download the `comboTree` files and put them in the `/www` folder of the app?

Comment: OK ...  I got it, i need to put all files in /www folder. May i ask why it is not combo box like it is shown in the picture above.

Comment: Awesome! Do you also have the `comboTreeStyle.css` file in the `www` folder?

Comment: I renamed the style.css that was included in the combTree to comboTreeStyle.css. However there is dash infront of item2 and when i select item2 is not selecting subitems. Please advise.

Comment: Have you seen the package `shinyTree` already? If that doesnt fit your needs I suggest you open a new question.

Comment: I tried shinyTree but it expands if you have long list.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61797628/select-items-and-its-sub-items-using-values-selected-from-a-javascript-based-sel